# Prove that for $μ$-almost every $x ∈ X$ $−1 ≤ \liminf f_n(x) ≤ \limsup f_n(x) ≤ 1$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a measure space $(X, M, μ),$ and suppose that

$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}μ\{x∈X :|f_n(x)|>1\}<∞.$
Prove that
for $μ$-almost every $x ∈ X$

$−1 ≤ \liminf f_n(x) ≤ \limsup f_n(x) ≤ 1$.

I am not so sure how to start this past qual problem.  Some help would be awesome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Apply Borel-Cantelli's lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Let $E_n = \{x : |f_n(x)| > 1\}$, so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E_n) < \infty$. Borel-Cantelli implies that $E_n$ does not happen infinitely often.

Hint 2: For any fixed $x$, $L = \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x)$ is the smallest subsequence of $f_n$. In other words, it is the smallest value such that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there are infinitely many values of $n$ which are less than $L+\epsilon$ but bigger than or equal to $L$.